# jsTree ui plugin not responding to configs, can't enforce select_limit

Tags: jstree

I can't get any of the ui configs to be responded to. The one that's really irking me is `select_limit`. This is my tree:

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({ 'core': {
                            'data': [
                                'Simple root node',
                                {
                                    'text': 'Root node 2',
                                    'state': {
                                        'opened': true,
                                        'selected': true
                                    },
                                    'children': [
                                        { 'text': 'Child 1' },
                                        'Child 2'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            'ui': {
                                'select_limit': 1,
                                "select_multiple_modifier": "alt"
                            },
                            'plugins': ['ui']
                        } });
```

My tree displays just fine and I can interact with it, I just can't for the life of me to get `select_limit` to be adhered to. Similarly, `select_multiple_modifier` isn't getting adhered to either. I must be doing some setup piece wrong, can anyone help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question...jsTree the select_limit feature is no longer supported, and nobody has bothered to update the documentation. There are probably plenty of features that are no longer supported.

Summary: Out of date documentation. Use jsTree at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple item of the core:

```
"core": {
  "multiple": false
}
```